# Python/Pandas: For loop to sum moving range and append to new column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, slice

I am fairly new to Python and Pandas so please forgive the uninformed question I'm posing here.

I have a dataframe (QReport) that looks like so:

```
DATE            STATE       SALES
2010-12-01       AL          10
2010-12-02       AL          13
2010-12-03       AL          16
2010-12-04       AL          10
2010-12-05       AL          10
2010-12-06       AL          2
2010-12-07       AL          5 
2010-12-08       AL          5
```

I'd like to create a seven day sales total column that sums seven day slices of sales and adds that total to a new '7DTotal' column. I've been trying to get at this through a for loop, setting x and y variables as 0 (zero) and 6 indexes which I try to increment each run through the loop:

```
x = 0
y = 6
for i in QReport:
    QReport['7DTotal'] = sum(QReport['SALES'][x:y])
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
```

This approach, however, is not working and is returning the same value for every row in the newly-added 7DTotal column.

Expected output would be:

```
DATE            STATE       SALES   7DTotal
2010-12-01       AL          10        0
2010-12-02       AL          13        0
2010-12-03       AL          16        0
2010-12-04       AL          10        0
2010-12-05       AL          10        0
2010-12-06       AL          2         0
2010-12-07       AL          5         66
2010-12-08       AL          5         61
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Also, will this be grouped by State?

Comment: I just added expected output, and edited the original dataframe a bit for purposes of helping explain expected output. It will be grouped by state, which actually leads to a follow-up question: I'll need to skip the first six rows for each state in the STATE column. I'm going to make an attempt at doing this myself for my own learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use rolling sum:

```
QReport['7DTotal'] = pd.rolling_sum(QReport.SALES, 7).fillna(0)
```

or

```
# Suggested by a commenter
QReport['7DTotal'] = QReport.rolling(7).sum().fillna(0)
```

(The first six elements of the column will be undefined, and `fillna` fills them with 0s.)

Comment: Rolling sum is deprecated. You should use QReport.rolling(7).sum()

Answer (score 0):

an easy solution would be

```
7_day_list = []

for index in QReport.

    avg = np.mean(QReport.loc[index:index+7, 'SALES'])

    7_day_list.append(avg)
```

hope that helps